# C# Linq-SQL query result returning nothing

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I'm fairly new to LINQ (and SQL at that). When trying to query my SQL Database in C# "Supervisors" (which contains only one column "Names" made of `nvarchar(50)` variables, none of which are *Null*), supvName ends up being an empty list. If I don't cast it as a List, `supvName` is of type`System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>` if that helps.

```
public addNewEmp()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    using (TestDataSet db = new TestDataSet())
    {
        var supvName = (from n in db.Supervisors
                        select n.Names).ToList();
        foreach (string n in supvName)
        {
            supv_cbox.Items.Add(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Even when using a Where statement, that one result doesn't show up, so I'm sure it's something simple in my code that I just can't seem to figure out. I've already tried using `AsEnumerable()` which didn't change anything.

EDIT: I'm doing this in VS 2010 WPF. Also when I Preview Data in TestDataSet.xsd, it does return the all the data in the Database.

Solution: The problem was when I used a DataSet. When I used a DataContext instead it worked perfectly fine. Thanks to your DataSet or DataContext question lazyberezovsky or I never would have tried that.
Using the following works:

```
var supvName = db.Supervisors.Select(m => m.Names);
supv_cbox.ItemsSource = supvName;
```

Thanks Surjah Singh too.

Comment: `TestDataSet` is a `DataSet` or `DataContext`?

Comment: TestDataSet is a DataSet

Comment: Then my solution below should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are enumerating over DataTable with Linq to DataSet, you should call `AsEnumerable()` on datatable and use `Field<T>` extension to get column value:

```
 var supvName = (from r in db.Supervisors.AsEnumerable()
                 select r.Field<string>("Names")).ToList();
```

BTW query variable `r` will be of `DataRow` type.

---

Your code can be simplified to:

```
 var names = db.Supervisors.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Names"));
 supv_cbox.DataSource = names.ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately supvName is still Count = 0 (tried both ways of implementing it). Could the problem possible be that I'm doing this in WPF instead of WinForm (I substituted DataSource out for DataContext and ItemsSource since i wasn't sure which)?

Comment: Recreated the window in WinForm and same issue XD Going to try using SQL commands and then DataContext to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Var supvName = Supervisors.Select(m=>m.Names);

   var supvName = from s in Supervisors.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     select s.Field<string>("Names");
```